# Get Reference in a child object, where parent has array of children with mongoose in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm working with mongoose in NodeJS and I have two main models, transactions and invoices, both could be inside a balance model, the models are defined like this:

```
const BalanceSchema = new Schema({
   transactions: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Transaction'}],
   invoices: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Invoice'}],
   references: [filesDescription],
});

const TransactionSchema = new Schema({
   paybook: PaybookTransaction,
});
```

I want to get all the transactions and know if they have a reference with Balance, The result that I except after make the consult:

```
[
 {
   _id: 'transaction_id'
   paybook: {}
   balance: 'balance_id'
 }
]
```

Is this possible, or Do I need do this with js?

UPDATE 1

Example Data:

I Have Table Transaction with data:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5988b1f62442837f5b8b911d"),
  "updatedAt" : ISODate("2017-08-09T19:47:14.657Z"),
  "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-08-09T19:47:14.657Z"),
  "paybook" : {
    "id_account" : "59763bc0244283dd798b4a57",
    "id_account_type" : "520d3aa93b8e778e0d000000",
    "id_credential" : "597a2fda0c212aa7648b58d3",
  },
}
```

And the table Balance with data like:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("598ba359ff32954ffb22da5a"),
  "updatedAt" : ISODate("2017-08-10T01:43:31.668Z"),
  "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-08-10T00:05:45.491Z"),
  "references" : [],
  "invoices" : [],
  "transactions" : [ 
      ObjectId("5988b1f62442837f5b8b911d")
  ]    
 }
```

I want to get all the Transactions that have a reference in Balance. Like I show you in the json reference.

Comment: It is not really clear what you are asking. Please show some sample data and the expected result so we can visibly see how the data is meant to relate.

Comment: So what are you asking for as a result? Do you just want the actual data from transactions to show inside the array instead of the `ObjectId` values? Or are you asking something else?

Comment: I want actual data from transactions, but also add some atribute like virtual o something called balance, that make a reference if that transaction is a record of Balance.

Comment: So what I am asking you is to please "show what that should look like". Because you do not understand how to do what you want you are also not explaining it very clearly. But if we can see the source documents ( which you have added ) and then also see a result that you expect to get, then someone can tell you how to get that result. We cannot read minds. You actually need to show what you expect.